# Terrible performance using push on an small observableArray of complex objects

Tags: knockout.js

I've got a pretty complex app, with one viewModel which has a list of records:

```
app.records = ko.observableArray([])
```

Using AJAX I grab some JSON from the server and stuff it into the array:

```
$.getJSON("/api/records", function(data){
    app.records($.map(data, function(item){
      r = new Record(item);
      return r;
    });
});
```

This works great for the 6 items in my test dataset, at least.  The app loads pretty much instantly.  But I also have a create new record button which does this:

```
$.post("/api/records", {}, function(record){
    r = new Record(record);
    console.log("About to push...");
    app.records.push(r);
    console.log("Pushed the new record.");
});
```

The first log line appears instantaneously, but the second line takes around 8 seconds to appear.  Commenting out the push makes the operation effectively instant.  I believe that the problem is arising from the fairly large number of fairly complicated computed variables I have; I think the push is causing it to recompute *EVERYTHING*. And yet, what's odd is that adding the six test items on page load is instant.

Can anyone give me some hints to debug this?  The app is not in a state where I can easily share the code or construct a JSFiddle that isolates the problem.  I'm reluctant to just blindly comment out lines to see if anything fixes the problem, since that could take a long time.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Or at least a general strategy?  :)

(I'm currently using the 2.1 release candidate; the problem occurs with Knockout 2.0 as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post on Niemeyer's blog: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, your theory about computed observables causing performance problems seems reasonable. Commenting them out using "binary search" strategy might be the fastest way to localize the problem. Or you can add logging to all you computed observables.